# Cannot replace app: app is automatically re-installed on boot

Tags: android-things

I have an app installed on Android Things, in a Raspberry Pi. I want to replace with a newer version, but it's overwritten with previous version after a reboot. That's weird!

This is what I've tried: Let's say the installed app package name is "com.myapp", I've run "adb uninstall com.myapp", and I get "Success". If I run uninstall command again, I get "Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]", so the app is completely uninstalled.
Then, I've modified package name in build.gradle to "com.mynewapp", and I install and run it using Run button from Android Studio. Now "com.mynewapp" appears when I run "adb shell pm list packages".
Now I restart the Pi using "adb shell reboot". And after reboot, the old app is running. Executing "adb shell pm list packages" shows my old package: "com.myapp", and "com.mynewapp" does not appear in the list.

How can I completely remove the old app, and replace with a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried deleting all SD contents, and flash latest Android Things image, and I realized SD card is corrupt. I replaced SD card, and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app using:

```
adb uninstall <pkg name>
```

Comment: I'm already uninstalling it that way. But it's automatically reinstalled on each reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can not uninstall the app which you packed in the OS image and flashed in the SD card using adb (returns the error which you encountered `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]`). Only you can uninstall the app which you installed using adb or android studio.That is why first time you are seeing success,which is uninstalling the overwritten version but next time as you are actually trying to uninstall the OEM version of your app so,you are seeing this error.

Just format and reflash the SD card with only Android things OS (without your app) then install your app using adb/android studio,now you will have only the uninstallable copy of your app in the sd card. So you can replace or do whatever you like with that app as like normal app downloaded from playstore.

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't pack de app in the OS. I installed it using Android studio